# Getting the following error - TypeError: cartItems.reduce is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect, redux-selector

I'm trying to count the number of items in an array called cartItems with the reduce function. But it throws off this weird error every time. My selectors code for redux -

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectCart = state => state.cart;

export const selectCartItems = createSelector(
  [selectCart],
  cart => cart.cartItems
);

export const selectCartHidden = createSelector(
  [selectCart],
  cart => cart.hidden
);

export const selectCartItemsCount = createSelector(
  [selectCartItems],
  cartItems =>
    cartItems.reduce(
      (accumalatedQuantity, cartItem) =>
        accumalatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity,
      0
    )
);
```

The component where I'm using the selector is below. I'm not destructuring it in the mapStateToProps function but directly passing the selector.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { toggleCartHidden } from "../../Redux/cart/cart.actions";
import { selectCartItemsCount } from '../../Redux/cart/cart.selectors';
import { ReactComponent as ShoppingIcon } from '../../assets/shopping-bag.svg';
import './cart-icon.styles.css';

const CartIcon = ({ itemCount, toggleCartHidden }) => (
    <div className='cart-icon' onClick={toggleCartHidden}>
        <ShoppingIcon className='shopping-icon' />
        <span className='item-count'>{itemCount}</span>
    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    itemCount: selectCartItemsCount(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    toggleCartHidden: () => dispatch(toggleCartHidden())
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps)
(CartIcon);
```

This is the cart reducer -

```
import CartActionTypes from './cart.types';
import { addItemToCart } from './cart.utils';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  hidden: true,
  cartItems: []
};

const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CartActionTypes.TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        hidden: !state.hidden
      };
    case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cartReducer;
```

Cart utility function -

```
export const addItemToCart = (cartItems, cartItemToAdd) => {
    const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
      cartItem => cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
    );
  
    if (existingCartItem) {
      return cartItems.map(cartItem =>
        cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
          ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
          : cartItem
        )
    }
  
    return [...cartItems, { ...cartItemToAdd, quantity: 1 }];
  };
```

[image]

Comment: What is the shape of your state in redux? What is `state.cart` and `state.cart.cartItems`? NM, you aren't even using the selector in your `mapStateToProps` yet... so what is `state.cart` then that you rename to `cartItems`? Did you intend to destructure `cartItems` from `state.cart` instead: `mapStateToProps = ({ cart: { cartItems } }) => ({...`?

Comment: @DrewReese cart is the reducer and cartItems is the array of items. I did destructure it. I've edited the answer to show how I've used it in the respective component.

Comment: did you try to remove the square bracket wrapped `selectCart`, `selectCartItems` in `createSelector`?

Comment: @tuan.tran no I've kept them in the selector actually

Comment: @tuan.tran That is a valid reselect syntax for input selectors.

Comment: I'm wondering why reduce is not getting recognised.

Comment: I see, so the screen cap doesn't match your current code then. Can you provide your reducers so we may better see what your state may look like? It is because `cart.cartItems` is undefined at some point and the selector can'y call `reduce` of undefined.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit it

Comment: Does `addItemToCart` return an array *always*? Can you include *that* utility function in your question?

Comment: Everest's answer has done it. It's working now. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Sure, that could work, but it's a stop-gap, you've still some issue in your redux state. It will still fail if for any reason `cartItems` is defined and not an array.

Comment: Oh, well then I'll add the utils function. Tell me what you find. Edit- I've added it.

Comment: Thanks. That utility appears fine to me, I don't see any issues. An improvement upon Everest's answer, I believe, would be to provide the fallback value from your `selectCartItems` selector, `cart => cart.cartItems ?? []`, this way any consuming selectors will always be provided a valid input. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cardItems` is null or undefined, `cardItems.reduce` will trigger that error.

Using `cartItems || []` would be solution.

```
export const selectCartItemsCount = createSelector(
  [selectCartItems],
  cartItems =>
    (cartItems || []).reduce(
      (accumalatedQuantity, cartItem) =>
        accumalatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity,
      0
    )
);
```

Comment: And what if `cartItems` is some other non-array truthy value, like `{}`, `true`, `5`, etc?